# Conditionally traverse an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, underscore.js

I writing code that should mimic the functionality of Underscores's `_.each` method. However, with the code I have now...

```
var testArr = ['a','b','c'];

var eachFunc = function(collection, iterator) {
  if (Array.isArray(collection)) {
    for (var i = 0; i < collection.legnth; i++ ) {
      iterator(collection[i]);
    }
  } 
  else {
    for ( var property in collection ) {
      iterator(collection[property]);
    }
  }
};

console.log(eachFunc(testArr, console.log));
```

I only return `undefined`. I would expect to log 'a','b' then 'c' to the console. I have verified that `Array.isArray(testArr)` is returning `true` and that the `if` block is entered into. It's the `for` loop that I'm not entering into properly.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong with this `for` loop?

Comment: Your `for..loop` has a typo: `collection.legnth`

Answer (score 2):

1) Typo: `legnth`.

2) You can't pass `console.log` directly - it results in `Illegal invocation` error. Pass either `console.log.bind(console)` or anonymous function.

3) That `undefined` is returned value of your function.